QFT introduction: From point mechanics to the continuum
In any introductory quantum field theory course, one gets introduced with the modification of the classical Lagrangian and the conjugate momentum to the field theory lagrangian (density) and conjugate momentum (density). I think it is crucial to understand how they are modified, because this is basically where the whole game of quantum field theory starts. At the moment I have a problem with the prescription how these modifications are motivated and the particular results.
We define the classical Lagrangian $$L = \sum\limits_i L(q_i(t), \dot{q_i}(t), t) \tag1$$ as the sum over a discrete set of d.o.f., as well as the conjugate momentum $$p_i=\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{q_i}}.$$ On the other side the field theory version of the Lagrangian is $$L = \int d^3x (Ld)(\phi(x), \partial_\mu\phi(x), x^\mu),\tag2$$ with $(Ld)$ defined as the Lagrangian density and $x$ being the four-position.
Since we go from discrete particle points to fields we do the following replacements according to A. Zee (pg. 19):

particle index $i \rightarrow \vec{x}$
$q \rightarrow \phi$
$q_i(t) \rightarrow \phi_{\vec{x}}(t)\equiv \phi(t,\vec{x}) = \phi(x)$, which makes perfect sense; and
$\sum\limits_i \rightarrow \int d^3x$

This prescription sends the classical $p_i$ to its field version $\pi(\vec{x})=\frac{\partial (Ld)}{\partial \dot{\phi}(\vec{x})}$ without a problem, as Peskin & Schroeder (pg. 16) can confirm.
Now I have two questions that won't let me sleep at night:

What do Peskin & Schroeder mean by $\dot{\phi}(\vec{x})$? How can we define a time derivative of a function, which depends on position only?

I know that the four derivative (and the four vector) inside the Lagrangian of (Eq. 2) is crucial to maintain Lorentz invariance, but that is the only thing that is not predicted by the four modification rules listed above, which would leave the time derivative of (Eq. 1) untouched just as for the case of the quantum field conjugate momentum density! So, where is the discrepancy? Is the prescription wrong or are any of the resulting formulas wrong?



the argument of $\phi$ is supposed to be a 4-vector $x=(t, \vec{x})$, not  a 3-vector. Because it is supposed to be Lorentz-invariant.

prescription should be more explicitly $q_i(t) \rightarrow \phi_\vec{x}(t)\equiv \phi(t, \vec{x})$.

You might want to read first classical field theory, where particles are replaced by (classical) fields. one example is the motion of a string, which has a continuum variable that identifies the position along it (a continuum of particles if you like). Both the newtonian and the relativistic versions.

You can use "\mathcal{L}" to get a curvy L symbol for the Lagrangian density, rather than using two symbols stuck together like "Ld."

@PatoGalmarini that is a really good advice! I didn't know that "classical field theory" was such a broad subject of its own. Can you please recommend any good book that has some content on the field theory Lagrangian?

it is usually included but often not taught in courses of classical mechanics, so Goldstein cover it in detail. But for what you need based on your knowledge,

I think an easy and quick to read book is susskind's https://www.amazon.com/Special-Relativity-Classical-Field-Theory/dp/1541674065/ref=m_crc_dp_lf_d_t1_d_sccl_1_2/140-7041370-2557223?pd_rd_w=3UWvL&content-id=amzn1.sym.a5144f00-3d78-40a4-aa84-7ff51eea31f7&pf_rd_p=a5144f00-3d78-40a4-aa84-7ff51eea31f7&pf_rd_r=9VK99TW4TW0CPZ9XP2QJ&pd_rd_wg=EfFGM&pd_rd_r=bde5e9e3-51dd-4fc1-88e4-70236a80cd1f&pd_rd_i=1541674065&psc=1, which is not a textbook but you will get from there what you need faster than getting all the details from a more formal book

Classical field theory textbook: https://www.amazon.com/Classical-Theory-Fields-THEORETICAL-PHYSICS-ebook/dp/B00JO9YQMG/

Soper.



What do Peskin & Schroeder mean by $\dot{\phi}(\vec{x})$? How can we define a time derivative of a function, which depends on position only?


Notation $\dot \phi$, when writing down Lagrangian/Hamiltonian of a field system (a system described by functions, instead of finite tuples of numbers) does not mean time derivative of a function of time $\phi(t)$ known at that stage, just as $\dot{q}$ does not mean time derivative of a known function of time $q(t)$ when writing down Lagrangian in analytical mechanics. In both cases, the dotted symbol refers to a Lagrangian argument conjugated to the coordinate (a rate of change of the coordinate/function value, a velocity). It would be closer to standard multi-variable calculus notation to denote it by a different letter, e.g. in analytic mechanics of single particle, we could write $L(x,v_x)$, and for a field system on a line with no constraints, we could write $L[\phi,v_\phi]$, and sometimes this is useful (like now), but this is not a standard notation; instead, since Lagrange, we use $L(x,\dot{x})$ and $L[\phi,\dot{\phi}]$, and it is understood that these symbols refer to values that are time derivatives of $x$ or $\phi$ only when these letters $x,\phi$ are redefined (e.g. in equations of motion) to refer to the actual motion $x^*(t)$ or $\phi^*(x,t)$, or to some other imagined motion.
The example Peskin & Schroeder use in section "Lagrangian Field Theory" uses a Lagrangian density $\mathcal{L}$ that depends on one time and three spatial derivatives of $\phi$ - which we denote $\partial_\mu\phi$. Again, these are just slight abuses of notation; in $L$, these are not meant to refer to values of derivatives, but to new arguments of the Lagrangian that acquire those values in equations of motion).
Realistic field models (like for a string, or a 2D sheet of steel, where $\phi$ can represent deviation of the body element from its equilibrium position) have values of fields at close points related by some equations (e.g. by a wave equation), and this kind of relation can be taken into account in the Lagrangian method only if the Lagrangian depends also on additional "generalized velocities" - spatial derivatives $\partial_i \phi$. Often, only first derivatives appear in Lagrangians, no second or higher ones; if $L$ depended only on $\dot{\phi}$, and not on $\partial_i \phi$, neighbouring parts of the system could be completely independent and thus uncorrelated (two neighbouring points could have wildly different values of $\phi$, which is not usual in physics).
However, for the purpose of passing to the Hamiltonian formalism, we can often take a Lagrangian, dependent on $\phi,\dot{\phi}$ and $\partial_i \phi$, and define another Lagrangian, with the same value, but dependent only on $\phi,\dot{\phi}$, and thus ignore the dependence on $\partial_i \phi$. That's why in the section Hamiltonian Field Theory they have a different  $\mathcal L$ that depends only on time "velocity" $\dot{\phi}$, not on spatial "velocities" $\partial_i\phi$.


I know that the four derivative (and the four vector) inside the Lagrangian of (Eq. 2) is crucial to maintain Lorentz invariance, but that is the only thing that is not predicted by the four modification rules listed above, which would leave the time derivative of (Eq. 1) untouched just as for the case of the quantum field conjugate momentum density! So, where is the discrepancy? Is the prescription wrong or are any of the resulting formulas wrong?


In the Lagrangian description of a field system, all spatial coordinates in spacetime are on equal footing, thus we don't have just one "velocity" $\dot{\phi}$, but four of them - $\partial_\mu\phi$. These can later refer to the actual values of directional derivatives in all directions in spacetime - either in the equations of motion we get from the Lagrangian, or in any actual or imagined motion $\phi^*(x,t)$.
Having four "velocities" in the Lagrangian and the Euler-Lagrangian equations is the easiest way, in 4D spacetime, to define the action principle with the Lagrangian formalism as close as possible to the original Lagrangian mechanics of particles, and to get the correct Euler-Lagrange equations for the field. Using just time "velocities", like in analytic mechanics, would not work with the action principle (at least, not in the usual way, maybe someone has thought up an alternative action principle which would use only time "velocities" in the Lagrangian).
All this does not follow from your 4 rules, it is a new (standard) feature of the usual Lagrangian formalism for fields. In this respect, it deviates from the straightforward adaptation of the other rules from Lagrangian mechanics to field systems. It is only in the (usual kind of) Hamiltonian formalism for fields, derived from the Lagrangian formalism via the Legendre transformation, where time gets its special role back again, and we have only one "momentum" $p_\phi$ function corresponding to one "coordinate" functon $\phi$, even though we had 4 "velocities" in the Lagrangian theory. This makes the Hamiltonian approach lose the manifest covariance of the Lagrangian approach, and things get sometimes hard to understand and error-prone (not only due to lost covariance, but also due to constraints). For example, in case of EM field, we have, in Hamiltonian formalism, only 4 momenta corresponding to 4 potentials $A_\mu$ (and only three of them are in the Lagrangian, so we have a constraint $p_{0} = \frac{\partial \mathcal L} {\partial~\partial_t A_0}=0$). We do not have 16 momenta, although in the Lagrangian formulation, there are 16 different "velocities" - partial derivatives  $\partial_\nu A_\mu$.



I know that the four derivative (and the four vector) inside the Lagrangian of (Eq. 2) is crucial to maintain Lorentz invariance, but that is the only thing that is not predicted by the four modification rules listed above, which would leave the time derivative of (Eq. 1) untouched just as for the case of the quantum field conjugate momentum density!


This does not seem to be a question, but rather seems like a long exclamatory statement. So, I'll just move on to the other questions...


What do Peskin & Schroeder mean by $\dot{\phi}(\vec{x})$? How can we define a time derivative of a function, which depends on position only?


The dot notation means the time derivative.
In the classical theory the $\phi(x)$ depends on $x = (ct, \vec x)$ and so depends on time.
In the quantum theory the Schrodinger operator $\hat \phi(\vec x)$ has no time dependence, but the Interaction picture or the Hamiltonian picture operator $\phi_I(\vec x, t)$ or $\phi_{H}(\vec x, t)$ has time dependence in the usual way via through the non-interacting Hamiltonian or full Hamiltonian, respectively. Unfortunately, the notation $\phi$ might be used for all three types of operators, since authors are lazy (and might expect you to understand which is which via context).


If there is indeed some discrepancy in 1., 2. or both, then either the prescription is wrong or the resulting formulas are wrong. What would be the right answers for each case?


The prescription is not "wrong," per se. But you have to be careful about whether or not you are talking about classical or quantum field theory.
In the classical field theory of $\phi(x)$ it is easy to find
$$
\pi(x) = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot\phi(x)}
$$
by straightforward differentiation.
This gives you some guidance or expectation of what the quantum $\hat\pi(\vec x)$ operator should "look like."
But, ultimately, in the quantum field theory you still need to check that the proper canonical commutation (or anti-commutation) relations hold if you want to consider $\hat \pi(\vec x)$ to be canonically conjugate to $\hat \phi(\vec x)$.

I updated the formulation of my question and I am aware now that the question that I have is a pure classical field theory question. But, the discrepancy in question 2. still remains there: the classical field momentum density equation you wrote is perfectly predicted by my 4-step-prescription. My problem is that the Lagrangian is not.

@Xhorxho I had already answered your question "2," which you have now relabeled as "1." The answer is the same. The symbol $\dot \phi(x)$ means the time derivative of $\phi(x)$, which depends on time... Your final question " So, where is the discrepancy?" is too vague to answer. Make it more precise.

If you are wondering where the time integration is, then you should remember that the action is the time integral of the lagrangian. So the action is the space-time integral of the Lagrange density. Is that what you are trying to ask about?

sorry, I meant the reformulated question 2 above. With "discrepancy" I mean that I do not take Eq. (2) as a result, if I apply my 4-step-prescription on Eq. (1), because there is no rule that sends the time $t$ to the four vector $x^\mu$. On the other side I can apply my 4-step-prescription on the classical conjugate momentum and obtain the field theory conjugate momentum. So there must be an inconsistency in my 4-step-prescription which should derive the field theory formulas from the classical point particle formulas.

Time is still special. It is not "the same thing" as space. You are "allowed" to treat time differentiation differently than space differentiation. I'm still not sure exactly what you are asking about... There is no rule that "sends" time to the four vector $x^\mu$, because why should there be? There does not seem to be any "inconsistency," as far as I can see. You can still have spatial derivatives in your lagrange density without "sending" time to $x^\mu$. Just think of the spatial derivative like a hopping term (like you might find in the Hubbard model).

I just want to know where Eq.(2) comes from. Indeed, it looks very familiar to Eq.(1) and thats why there seems to exist a prescription that replaces every symbol of Eq.(1) as described above. But if you go and replace every symbol of Eq.(1) one by one according to the prescription, there shouldn't be a four derivative in the second argument of $(Ld)$ in Eq.(2), but instead a time derivative (like you said: "time is still special") because the prescription doesn't dictate you what to do with t. Every change outside the prescription violates it, even if its for the sake of Lorentz-invariance.

@Xhorxho If you look at the classical lagrangian for a string of point masses, you will see there is a term that depends on $q_{i+1} - q_{i}$. Those terms turn into the terms that look like $\nabla \phi$.
